# Paper-input for paper-slider not working with post method

Tags: polymer

I am trying to use the following code. The one in which I used paper-input-decorator works. What can I do for the slider type?

```
<form is="ajax-form" action="test/x.php" method="post">
<paper-input-decorator floatingLabel label="Enter your email address*" type="text">
            <input id="input3" name="email" is="core-input" required>
</paper-input-decorator>

<paper-slider pin="true" immediateValue="true" min="0" max="5" name="slider" value="2.5">Trust Score</paper-slider>
</form>
```

Comment: "You can easily submit a <paper-input> or <core-input> element. Just place it in your <ajax-form>, and be sure it has a name attribute. In fact, any custom element form field with a name attribute can be handled by <ajax-form>, provided the value to send to the server is exposed via a value property on the element. " Is this statement not true then?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work even with a normal form
Have you watched the network requests that are sent ?
Could you submit a Plunkr ?

Comment: I just have php file which shows values for input but not for slider. I will look into what plunkr is.

Comment: The best way to debug post request is to use F12 on your browser and watch the request content. You will be able to see if the slider is posting something
http://plnkr.co/ is a website where you can put your code. It's easier to debug your code this way